# Realm Collection notification not firing for updates not impacting query

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I have run into an issue in Realm Objective-C v2.4.3 where the collection notification block is not firing for a modification if the modification does not affect the overall query results.

To give a simplified example.

A `Feed` object and `FeedItem` object. Feed has an `items` RLMArray property.

```
RLMArray<FeedItem *><FeedItem> *items
```

I have a collection notification block set up for RLMResults where the query is:

```
[Feed objectsWhere:@"ANY items.status > 0"]
```

Insertion changes will fire if I modify the status property from 0 -> 1. As would deletions if I had an upper bounds to the query and it moved out of that. However, any changes to a FeedItem's status property that continues to match the query (such as modifying it from 1 -> 2) will not trigger the notification change block as the overall query results are not impacted by this change.

I would've expected this change to fall under a modification as mentioned in the collection docs?

> - You’re notified about modifications whenever a property of an object
>   has changed, which was previously part of the collection and is still
>   part of it.
> - You modify the age property of a Dog belonging to that Person.
> - This makes it possible to discretely control the animations and
>   visual updates made to the content inside your UI, instead of
>   arbitrarily reloading everything each time a notification occurs.

Am I missing something to get this functionality working? The CollectionView's datasource is the RLMResults and I would like to reload an individual CollectionViewCell to reflect the update to the FeedItem's status.

Comment: This seems like a bug in Realm. Would you be willing to file a ticket at our GitHub issues tracker (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues), and/or send a demo project that reproduces this issue to help@realm.io?

Comment: Thanks @AustinZ. I commented on two existing issues. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4305#issuecomment-283688989 and https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3885#issuecomment-283274197

Comment: Excellent! Apologies for not noticing those earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I have worked around this by adding a `lastModified` property to `Feed` and then when making a change on `FeedItem` I update last modified using the inverse relationship.

`self.feed.lastModified = [NSDate date];`

Not that great, but it fires a modification change in the collection notification which is what I was after.

Happy to accept another answer that has a better way to achieve this.

Also found two existing Realm github issues which I've commented on

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4305#issuecomment-283688989

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3885#issuecomment-283274197